# $l^2$ is not compact

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

> Prove that the space $l^2$ (of real series $a_n$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_i^2$ converges) is not compact.

I want to use the open cover $\{\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_i^2<n\mid n\in\mathbb{Z}^+\}$ and show that it has no finite subcover. To do that, I must prove that for any $n$, the set $\{\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_i^2<n\}$ is an open set.

So let $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_i^2<n$. Suppose it equals $n-\alpha$. I must find $\epsilon$ such that for any series $\{b_i\}\in l^2$ with $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}(a_i-b_i)^2<\epsilon$, we have $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}b_i^2<n$.

But $(a_i-b_i)^2$ has the term $-2a_ib_i$. How should I deal with that?

Comment: The set you have is $\{a | \|a\|_2 < \sqrt{n} \}$ which is open.

Comment: @copper.hat So it's open because it is an open ball (with center being the series $0,0,0,\ldots$ and radius $\sqrt{n}$), and any open ball is an open set. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes. It is a metric space; a set $A$ is open **iff** for any point $x \in A$ there is some $\epsilon>0$ such that $B(x,\epsilon) \subset A$. It is straightforward to prove that an open ball is an open set using the triangle inequality.

Comment: Ok all clear, copper.hat. Thank you!

Comment: So: in fact you prove that any metric space with infinite diameter is not compact.

Comment: @PJMiller Why would showing that ${\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_i^2 <n}$ is open for each $n$ lead to showing that there is no finite subcover?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the straight line that is the set of all scalar multiples of one non-zero element of $\ell^2$.  It's a closed subspace.  If the whole space were compact, then that line would be compact.  But that line is homeomorphic to the ordinary real line.

Answer (score 1):

There're two easy ways to prove that $\ell_2$ is not compact. First, is to say that its dimension is infinite, hence closed unitary ball is not compact, hence the space itself is not compact.

Another way to see this is to find a bounded sequence which doesn't have a convergent subsequence; as a matter of fact, a sequence of basis vectors doesn't converge in norm (nor does any its subsequence); it's easy to see by checking Cauchy criterion.

Comment: By a sequence of basis vectors is meant a [Schauder basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_basis) rather than an algebraic basis.

Comment: The OPs approach is pretty straightforward as well...

Comment: So: showing that the unit ball is not compact is harder than showing the whole space is not compact.  The whole space not compact holds even in finite-dimensional cases...

Comment: @GEdgar =) Well, the non-compactness of unitary ball in infinite dimension is a known theorem and can be evoked without knowledge of its proof; direct proof of non-compactness of $\ell_2$ requires some work.

Comment: @kahen of course.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the following approach more so than the ones already mentioned, perhaps it's useful for somebody else at some point:

Let $f\colon \ell^2\to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $(x_n)_n\mapsto x_1$. Then $f$ is not bounded and thus $\ell^2$ can't be compact.

Comment: It's actually even simpler: a compact in a metric space ought be bounded.

Comment: The sequence maps to the single value of the first element? Why is $f$ not bounded?

Comment: @Diger Note that $f$ is real valued. Let $M$ be any real number, let $x_1=|M|+1$, $x_n=0$ for $n>1$, and $x=(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$. Then $|f(x)|=||M|+1|=|M|+1>|M|\geq M$. That is,  $\forall M\in \mathbb{R},\exists x\in \ell^2,\; |f(x)|>M$, precisely the negation of boundedness: $\exists M\in\mathbb{R},\forall x\in\ell^2,\; |f(x)|\leq M$.

Comment: So, for the same reason $\ell^2_n$ (the space of finite dimensional vectors) is not compact?