# Best possible inequality for $\int_0^1 (1-x^2)(g(x))^2$

Tags: real-analysis, integral-inequality

I'm looking for the best possible inequality of the form $$\int_0^1 (1-x^2)\left(g(x)\right)^2 \, {\rm d}x \leq c \int_0^1 (g(x))^2 \, {\rm d}x$$ for some constant $c$. Cleary $c=1$ works, but I want better. By the intermediate value theorem we have $$\int_0^1 (1-x^2) (g(x))^2 \, {\rm d}x = (g(\xi))^2 \int_0^1 (1-x^2) \, {\rm d}x = (g(\xi))^2 \cdot \frac{2}{3}$$ for some $\xi \in (0,1)$, so maybe $c=2/3$ would be even possible.

I also tried using Lagrange-multipliers by going over to the normalized function $\int_0^1 (g(x))^2 = 1$. The Method of Lagrange would then give $$\int_0^1 (1-x^2) 2g(x)\delta g(x) \, {\rm d}x = \lambda \int_0^1 2g(x)\delta g(x) \, {\rm d}x$$
or
$$\int_0^1 2g(x) \delta g(x) \left[1-x^2 - \lambda\right]  {\rm d}x = 0$$
for arbitrary variations $\delta g(x)$, but this obviously doesn't work somehow... I don't know why.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you consider $g(x)=(1-x)^n$ you have

$$ \int_{0}^{1}(1-x^2)g(x)^2\,dx = \frac{n+2}{2n^2+5n+3}, \qquad \int_{0}^{1}g(x)^2\,dx = \frac{1}{2n+1} $$
hence you cannot replace $c$ with something less than one.
The idea was just to consider functions pretty much concentrated in a right neighbourhood of the origin.

Comment: Do you know what issue there is with the Lagrange method?

Comment: @Diger: the domain. The stationary "functions" here are actually distributions. You may also replace $g(x)=(1-x)^n$ with the function that equals $1$ over $[0,1/n]$ and zero otherwise.

Comment: You mean $g(x) = C\cdot \delta(x\pm \sqrt{1-\lambda})$ would be a solution for some constant $C$?

Comment: Why $\lambda=1$? Btw, $\int_0^1 g(x)^2$ can not be made to unity in this case!?

Comment: It is clear that there are continuous functions such that LHS $\geq (1-\varepsilon)$ RHS for any $\varepsilon > 0$. In order to apply Lagrange multipliers properly you need a compact set, and $L^2(0,1)$ is not a compact set.

Comment: In equivalent terms, you can make $\int_{0}^{1}x^2 g(x)^2\,dx$ as small as you like in comparison with $\int_{0}^{1}g(x)^2\,dx$.

Comment: I'm not really sure I get what you want to say regarding the compactness. Who is saying I'm considering $L^2(0,1)$? Couldn't it just be $L^2[0,1]$ which is compact? How does this affect the present situation?

Comment: $[0,1]$ is compact but $L^2[0,1]$ is not. Think of $g(x)$ as a Fourier series and consider https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/422913/l2-is-not-compact. We have to be careful in applying the standard theory of Lagrange multipliers: we are not granted that the solutions are continuous, neither functions (they can be distributions, like in the current case)